# How to check if a scroll view exists

Tags: android, if-statement

I was wondering how you check if a scrollView exists for an if statement. The current code for creating the scollView is below. Any help will be much appreciated :)

Code:

```
public void tickBox(int i){
    //Create GUI
    LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);
    ScrollView sc = new ScrollView(this);
    sc.setId(i + 100);
    if (/*If statement to be made*/){
        mainView.addView(sc);
    }
    //My other code
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it can be as:

```
if (mainView.findViewById(i + 100) == null){
    mainView.addView(sc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( sc != null ) {
        mainView.addView(sc);
    }
```